# Django administration view: how to remove auto generated permissions?

Tags: django, django-admin

Django administration view automatically generates permissions for all modules and tables - admin, auth, contenttypes etc. Is it possible to remove this permissions from 'Available user permissions' so i can see only permissions that i think are relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in an elegant manner.  You would need to either override the template or go mucking in the admin code (django philosophy: "the admin is not your app").

It's best to create your own interface.